# Passing array object as method arguments in java

Tags: java, arrays, arguments

i am trying to read number of image files and i want to compare them with each other. I have created an array object of size 5 and assigned 5 images to it. I tried to compare each images by passing array object to method. But it shows me an error. Can anyone help me?

```
File[] f= new File[5];

 f[1]= new File("p1.png");

 f[2]= new File("p2.png");

 f[3]= new File("p3.png");

 f[4]= new File("p4.png");

 f[5]=new file("p5.png");

 for(int i=1;i<5;i++)

{

 compare(f[i],f[i++]);

}

public void compare(File fi[1],File fi[2])
{


    BufferedImage image = ImageIO.read(fi[1]);
 int width = image.getWidth(null);

  int height = image.getHeight(null);

int[][] clr=  new int[width][height]; 

  BufferedImage images = ImageIO.read(fi[2]);

 int widthe = images.getWidth(null);

   int heighte = images.getHeight(null);

int[][] clre=  new int[widthe][heighte]; 
}
```

Comment: I recommend taking a step back and working through some fundamental Java tutorials.

Comment: each time you are passing same two object, replace  'compare(f[i],f[i++]);' with  'compare(f[i],f[i+1]);'

Comment: what is this.... !!!!
int width = image.getWidth(null);
int height = image.getHeight(null);

Answer (score 2):

Several issues:

1. This line

   ```
   public void compare(File fi[1],File fi[2])
   ```

   is a syntax error. It should be

   ```
   public void compare(File f1, File f2)
   ```

   (obviously the names of the args are up to you).
2. When calling it, use

   ```
   compare(f[i], f[i + 1]);
   ```

   rather than `i++`.
3. This line tries to write to an array slot that doesn't exist:

   ```
    f[5]=new file("p5.png");
   ```

   ...because your array is defined as `new File[5]`, which means it has slots `0` through `4`. You'll need to change all of your lines setting values in the slots to use `0` through `4` instead of `1` through `5`.
4. Your loop boundaries are wrong. They should be `0` and `< f.length - 1` instead of `1` and `< 5` here:

   ```
   for(int i = 0; i < f.length - 1; i++)
   ```

   There are two reasons for doing `< f.length - 1` rather than `< 5`. First, because you use `i + 1` in the body of the loop, you want to stop one slot early. Secondly, if you change the length of `f` later, you'd have to remember to update the `5` on the `for` loop as well, which is a maintenance problem waiting to happen. (Note that the loop is to `i < f.length - 1` because you use `i + 1` in the loop body. Normally a loop is `0` through `< length`, but not in this case.)

I stopped reading the code at that point, so can't guarantee there aren't other fundamental issues. I recommend working through some basic Java tutorials.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. When i did the 1st one as you said, i still get error in the line public void compare(File f1,File f2)

Answer (score 0):

Arrays are indexed from 0, not 1. Instead of this:

```
File[] f= new File[5];
 f[1]= new File("p1.png");
 f[2]= new File("p2.png");
 f[3]= new File("p3.png");
 f[4]= new File("p4.png");
 f[5]=new file("p5.png");
```

Use this:

```
File[] f= new File[5];
 f[0]= new File("p1.png");
 f[1]= new File("p2.png");
 f[2]= new File("p3.png");
 f[3]= new File("p4.png");
 f[4]=new file("p5.png");
```

Answer (score 0):

change your method signature to

```
public void compare(File fi1,File f2)
```

Answer (score 0):

There are a few problems with your code.

First, your for loop should use the exit condition `i < f.length-1`

Second, your compare method does not need the array references:

```
public void compare(File f1, File f2) {
    ....
}
```

Third, indexes start at 0, not 1.

Answer (score 0):

Change this line

`public void compare(File fi[1],File fi[2]){`

to

`public void compare(File fi,File fi2) {`

or

`public void compare(File[] fi,File[] fi2) {`

Answer (score 0):

**Array of size 5 starts from 0-4 but
 you are accessing index of 5**

```
File[] f= new File[5];

 f[1]= new File("p1.png");

 f[2]= new File("p2.png");

 f[3]= new File("p3.png");

 f[4]= new File("p4.png");

 f[5]=new file("p5.png");  // This is wrong
```

value should be from 0-4

And also

```
 for(int i=1;i<5;i++)
{
 compare(f[i],f[i++]);
```

**if i==4 then i++ will become, so you'll get ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException**

```
 }
```

I will don't mention rest of errors as Rest of the answers have already posted them

Answer (score 0):

You mean compare each other?

```
for (int i = 0; i < f.length; i++)
    {
        for(int j=i+1;j<f.length;j++){
         compare(f[i], f[j]);
        }
    }
```

Answer (score -1):

```
    File[] f= new File[6];

     f[1]= new File("p1.png");

     f[2]= new File("p2.png");

     f[3]= new File("p3.png");

     f[4]= new File("p4.png");

     f[5]=new file("p5.png");

     for(int i=1;i<5;i++)  
    {   
     compare(f[i],f[i+1]);
    }

    public void compare(File f1,File f2)
    {
     BufferedImage image = ImageIO.read(f1);
     BufferedImage image = ImageIO.read(f2);
 // compare as you like

}
```